# Stereo sound through whole 5.1 speaker set - is it possible with WinXP or 7?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, stereo, 5.1, mixing

Is it possible to "upmix" (split) stereo output from games, winamp, youtube and so on through 5.1 speaker set? Movies from DVD or some games uses all 6 speakers, but most of today's usage does not.

I know foobar2000 can upmix stereo MP3 to all speakers, I'd like to process all stereo sound that way.

Is there any solution for Windows XP or 7?

**EDIT:**
I'm talking about onboard 5.1 sound output AC97 nForce2 chipset in my case. Definitely low-end.
**EDIT2:**
No digital output, 3 analog mini-jacks there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Skelly](https://superuser.com/questions/22879/stereo-sound-through-whole-5-1-speaker-set-is-it-possible-with-winxp-or-7/22884#22884) says, it would depend on your driver.

For me, it's this setting:

[image: screenshot of Realtek Audio Manager]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I spent about an hour setting up my speakers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, though it might depend on your sound card drivers. I use a Creative X-Fi card and the Creative Control Panel app lists two faux surround modes for upmixing stereo: Stereo Surround and Stereo Xpand. If I remember correctly, the former option does what you need, it basically puts the stereo signal from the front L+R spakers in the rear L+R speakers too, I don't remember what happens to the center channel though, it's been a while since I've used a surround speaker set.

Check your driver controls for any similar-looking options.

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware has a `5.1` output path, the upmix will be supported.

If you are wiring your audio output to external equipment through a stereo path,
you will be limited to that.