# Why does my 5.1 surround work in testing only?

Tags: audio, speakers, surround-sound, 5.1

I've got a 5.1 speaker setup. In both this SoundMax utility (I think it came with my motherboard), and in the Windows 7 sound test, all 5.1 speakers work properly, but that's the only time that I can get audio to come out of the rear speakers and the center channel. When playing games, video, music, etc., I only seem to get 2.1 speakers worth of sound, even though I've configured everything for 5.1 surround sound.

How can I get my 5.1 surround sound working during actual use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know about games, however with media, the sample has to actually be encoded with 4 or 5 channels, nomatter what the media players settings are. try to fimd some 5.1 speaker test files on google to verify they work on your favorite media player. most have a 2x stereo option or something similar which will play the same stereo sound from both the front and back pairs of speakers, even for files that dont support more than 2 channels.

Comment: You're right. I think it was the audio sources. I downloaded a 5.1 test file and I could hear audio out of the other speakers. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/questions/96796/use-all-5-1-speakers-with-a-2-1-audio-source) links to a useful Winamp plug-in

Comment: Try this test file: http://www.lynnemusic.com/surround/www_lynnemusic_com_surround_test.ac3