# I need some help connecting a 5.1 audio system to my laptop

Tags: laptop, audio, tv, surround-sound, 5.1

I purchased a [Panasonic SC-PT470](http://panasonic.ae/en/manuals/SC-PT470.pdf) 5.1 channel stereo system.  I am trying to connect it to my Win11 laptop, a [Lenovo Ideapad 320-15ISK](https://%20https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad320-15isk_320x-15isk_320-15ikb_320x-15ikb_320-15ikbtouch_ug_en_201704.pdf) but I am not even sure if the way I've set it up will work.

My laptop is connected to my TV via HDMI and the TV is sending audio to the receiver through an optical cable.

It works fine when running apps like Netflix on the TV itself, but when I try to play a game on my laptop, the rear speakers duplicate the front ones instead of having distinct channels.  The subwoofer does work, and the center speaker does not play.

I am thinking the laptop cannot detect that there is a 5.1 audio output since the TV gets in the way, when I look at audio settings on the control panel it is as if I only had a 2-channel stereo system hooked up.

If that is the case, is there a way to maybe force the laptop to send a 5.1 audio signal even if it cannot detect the speakers?

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad 320-15ISK

Comment: The DVD player model? I don't think so, the label on the front panel says SA-PT470

Comment: I figured it out.  The system is SC-PT470:  main unit SA-PT470, Front speakers SB-HF470, Center speaker SB-HC470, Surround speakers SB-HS470, Subwoofer SB-HW460

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use all 5.1 speakers with a 2.1 audio source](https://superuser.com/questions/96796/use-all-5-1-speakers-with-a-2-1-audio-source)

Comment: Hm, no, no luck, all the boxes but Front Left and Right Left are grayed out, it must definitely be the TV getting in the way and thus the laptop not detecting the rest of the speakers, so probably there's no way of getting a 5.1 output.
Thanks a lot, though!

Comment: I am betting you didn't pick the right audio-OUT.  I have this exact same setup and have no problems.  xbox, firestick, laptop, desktop -> tv -> yamaha reciever 5.1 surround (through optical ONLY).  Not bragging! :)  Letting you know there is hope.  Make sure your audio is going to HDMI and not the local laptop.  HDMI audio should not show only 2 channels.. you are probably looking at the wrong card.

Comment: Oh.. and BTW.. I gave up on this for months and just got it working recently.  DONT GIVE UP.  You got the hardest part done in that the TV is already set to output to optical.  Inspired by Elden Ring(tm) sounding like crap.

Comment: It's funny that no one even talked about TV model.