How to force or mimic surround sound for center speaker when only stereo is available?
My setup is:

Denon AVR-X1700H 7.2, with 5.1 speaker config
Roku ultra
Spectrum App

The spectrum app, and many others, only provide stereo audio. And since my AV receiver is physically setup for 5.1 surround sound, the sound for the spectrum app comes out of only the front left and front right speakers (and s sub).  The center channel does not output any sound, and since my setup has the front left and right speakers in the corners of the room (about 10ft fro the TV), the audio sounds "dislocated" (for lack of a better word), like it's coming from some sort of PA system and not at all from the video/tv in the center of the wall.
I understand that the spectrum app is the root cause here since spectrum states it only supports stereo, but I'm wondering what options exist to somehow produce sound out of the center speaker?  My only ideas this far are:
1  change speaker configuration in the AV receiver to output to all channels.  I'm not sure exactly how to do this, but the downsides seem to be that I would lose whatever left/right sound separation exists in the default config. Also, I think this would require manually changing the config on the AV receiver whenever I watch this app, and then reverting back whenever I watch other apps, like. Netflix.
2  Insert some sort of audio manipulation between the roku and AV to mimic surround sound. Maybe this is somehow possible with a raspberry pi or similar sbc, but I have no idea what software could be employed or how, just spitballing some sort of magically intelligent sound processor that would real-time convert/trascode audio signals when needed.
Are there any options to explore here, or am I just stuck with stereo?

https://superuser.com/questions/96796/use-all-5-1-speakers-with-a-2-1-audio-source?rq=1

@DavidT thank you for the reference, that's almost my exact problem, only I don't have any pc or windows involvement, just the devices I listed.  I know this question may be in the wrong SO site, but I couldn't find a better one and so I thought it would be best to start here.
